# Global variables in python, undesired behavior.

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

here i am updating x and if I print y after I updated x, y will show the reflection. However, in the first example y doesn't show that change. This is where I get lost at. Can someone explain this to me?

```
x = 2
y = x + 3
###  printing y will yield 5
x = 8    # ok am I updating the same storage space that x pointed to, or is abandoning it and creating
         # another with a value of 8?
###  printing y will still yield 5 (why is that? if Y always points to x and adds 3 to it?)

in contrast with this:

x = [1,2,3]
y = [x,4,5,6]
x[0] = 50
y[2] = 80
z = y[:] + [100,101,1020
```

Comment: Think of `x[0]=50` as shorthand for `x.__setitem__(0, 50)`. Don't let the assignment operator throw you off.

Answer (score 4):

`x = 2`  A new object with the value 2 is created, x refers to it

`y = x + 3`  A new object with the value 5 is created, y refers to it

`x = 8` A new object with the value 8 is created, x now refers to it.  The reference count on the object with value 2 is decremented, and is a candidate for garbage collection.

`x = [1,2,3]`  A new list ("object of type/class list") is created, and x refers to it.

`y = [x,4,5,6]`  A new list-object is created, and y refers to it. The previous object `x` referred to is basically gone. It's so-called "garbage" and may be collected by the so-called "garbage collector".

`x[0] = 50`  Changes the first element of the list referenced by x to 50

`y[2] = 80`  Changes the third element of the list referenced by y to 80

`z = y[:]`   A new list-object is created, which contains a copy of the elements refered to by y.  This doesn't copy the reference (x) in the first element. See `copy.deepcopy()` for that.

Comment: This is a very good answer, but i don't think it gets to the point OP doesn't seem to get.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer: OK, I accept it is not begineer friendly, but that's the best I can do.  I guess the point that the OP does not get is that variable names refer to objects.  C programmers often have this issue because they think of Python references as pointers to an area of virtual memory.

Comment: I was under the impression that OP got confused because the int value for y was processed immediately and didn't depend anymore on x.

Comment: There you go.  I'm confused over what has the OP confused.

Comment: I don't *know*, but it seems to me that OP was confused that `x = 2; y = x + 3;x = 8` doesn't set y to 11, since he specified a "formula" for y.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> #### printing y will still yield 5 (why is that? if Y always points to x and adds 3 to it?)

Your misunderstanding starts here. `y` does *not* point to x. `y`has the value 5. It almost sounds like you are trying to equate this with the model of a spreadsheet where cells can have formulas. Coding is not like that; when you assign something to `y`, you are assigning a value, not a formula.

Comment: Exactly.  `y` is a number, not a function.  The value is computed at the time of assignment and then it's done.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `=` operator with a variable name as the left hand value, this binds (or re-binds) the name on the left side to the object on the right side. `y = x + 3` makes `y` refer to an `int` object with the value `5`, and then `x = 8` makes the variable x refer to an `int` object with the value `8`.

The the left hand side is something like `x[0]`, you're doing item assignment, and only changing the 0th item in `x`; the name `x` still refers to the original list, which is also a member of the list pointed to by `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a set of boxes. X is the name of a box, as is y, when we are talking about single variables rather than arrays.
So x = 2 means put a 2 in the box labelled x.
y = x + 3 means take what's in box x, add 3 to it and put it in box y.
x = 8 means replace what's in box x with 8.
y has already been worked out so can't be changed.

With arrays like x = [1, 2, 3] x doesn't refer to a box, it refers to a collection of boxes.
Its like x refers to box 1, 2 and 3, which each happen to have the values 1 2 & 3 in them.
So if I change the contents of the first box in the list x indicates, x itself is unchanged, it still is the list of boxes - of which one of them has had it's value changed.
y in this case is a list of boxes, of which the first one is not really a box, but contains a pointer to another set of boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want that behaviour, you have to use a function:

```
>>> x = 2
>>> y = lambda: x + 3
>>> y()
5
>>> x = 8
>>> y()
11
```

because x is immutable, so assigning will always create new objects that will not reflect future changes.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that this is what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your example, and replace the variables:

Original:

```
x = 2
y = x + 3
###  printing y will yield 5
x = 8    # x now holds the value of 8 instead of 2
###  printing y will still yield 5 (why is that? if Y always points to x and adds 3 to it?)

in contrast with this:

x = [1,2,3]
y = [x,4,5,6]
x[0] = 50
```

Replaced:

```
x = 2
y = 2 + 3
###  printing y will yield 5
x = 8    
###  printing y will still yield 5 because it is set to 2+3


x = [1,2,3] 
y = [[1,2,3],4,5,6] #[1,2,3] is the same list as x
x[0] = 50 # x still holds the value of the same list, 
#however you're changing the value of the first element of the, 
#you're not changing x itself though.
```

In the first example, you're changing the value of x itself.  In the second you're changing a property of x, while leaving x as the same value.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = x + 3
```

The value for y gets immediately computed. That's all.